# Angular 5: Document Download returning "Failed to load PDF"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to download a pdf file from an API given a documentId. However, the document when open reads "Failed to load PDF" I've also checked the chrome dev tools and no network call is being made to the API, can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
downloadDocument(document) {
  // this.documentDownload.emit(document.attachmentId);
  this.documentUrl = this/is/a/api/url

  const blob = new Blob([this.documentUrl], {type: 'application/pdf' }); //octet-stream
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, url.split(':')[1] + '.pdf');
    return;
  }
  const a = window.document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = document.filename;
  a.click();
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); }, 100);
    // return url;
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont see any http calls

Comment: All the examples I saw just used a blob, would i make the call before or after createObjectURL. If I am missing something Key forgive me. Still quite new to angular~

Comment: well from my knowledge of angular, js and http calls, you need to do a http call else no call is made

Comment: Yeah, I read around a bit more and I am trying to put it in.

Comment: I guess I am doing it wrong b/c it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Just construct an anchor tag that points to the service end point

```
<a [href]="constructServiceEndPoint()" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And have the function constructServiceEndPoint return a string representing the end point. Make sure your service sets the filename header.